# Detecting hard coded label text in PHP application

Tags: php, javascript, label, static-analysis, template-engine

Is there a way to detect hard coded label text that potentially needs to be replaced by a label within a PHP application? I am not just talking about PHP files but also about javascript, xml files and SMARTY/TWIG templates. Are there standard procedures within multilingual applications?

Comment: Text is text. You can `str_replace` it, `preg_replace` it or use several other similar functions to work with it. For example, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783918/using-php-code-in-html-in-php/9784039#9784039).

Comment: Thought there might be some kind of 'phpmd style' rule that just recognizes text (except docblock and inline annotations) and shows potential text that needs to be treated by any kind of translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP you could iterate over the template files using [**`token_get_all()`**](http://php.net/token-get-all).

You'd look at `T_STRING` tokens and then check if they are not in the same format your placeholders are. For example: "All Uppercase" or something like that.

---

For xml it's pretty much the same deal, iterating over the nodes and checking if any text content is flying around where you would only expect placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Our Search Engine is a tool for efficient searching across large code bases, indexing the language lexical structure to speed the search.    It is thus faster than grep, and allows much more nuanced queries in terms of those language lexemes.

A query is in the form of a series of lexemes with various constraints. One might write a query:

```
   I=*foo* '.' S=*hello
```

meaning:  "find an Identifier containing 'foo', followed by a concatenation operator, followed by a literal String having the letters 'hello' at the end.  For PHP, the generic lexeme S represent all the string-type literals (squoted strings, dquoted strings, heredocs, etc; you can search for them specifically if you want).   Because the search engine understands lexical syntax, it won't get confused by intervening whitespace, linebreaks or comments, so you don't have to know the layout to find it.  (It will find comment tokens with constraints if you insist).

You don't have to put a constraint:

```
   I=*foo* '.' S
```

finds any identifier dot string combination.

The query

```
   S
```

by itself directly answers the OP's question of "where are literal strings?" of any type.