# How to find in a string like '{$formLocation}' the 'Location' part?

Tags: php

I created a file `.tpl`, which contains strings like `{$formLocation}`, then I put the file content in a variable `$content`. I have to get  what's between `{$form`  and `}`

(ex. the
 '`Location`' part from the `{$formLocation}`, ). Any idea how? Maybe using regex?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783918/using-php-code-in-html-in-php/9784039#9784039) to this question, it should tell you what you want to know and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
preg_match_all('/{\$form([a-zA-Z]+)}/', $test, $matches);
```

Then you'll find the part between `{$form` and `}` in : `$matches[1][0]`, `$matches[1][1]`, and so on...