# PHP str_replace to include function/file as part of a Templating system

Tags: php, str-replace

Overview: I'm making a tempting system for my sites, which at the moment is going quite well and it is working how I would expect it to, the only problems arise when I would like something like {PAGE_SIDEBAR} to show the file template/sidebar.php or something similar.

I am using

```
//loads of other str_replace here
$body = str_replace("{PAGE_SIDEBAR}, include("template/sidebar.php"), $body);
echo $body;
```

this works, however it includes the file at the start of body, NOT where {PAGE_SIDEBAR} is. Where the tag is, it shows the number 1.

See screenshots for better explanation:

[How the rendered template looks before](http://www.jamesmoorhouse.co.uk/stack_overflow/str_replace/before_str_replace.png)

[Using the insert code above](http://www.jamesmoorhouse.co.uk/stack_overflow/str_replace/include_method.png)

Also, for point of interest, How it looks using file_get_contents() instead of include():  http:// www.jamesmoorhouse.co.uk/stack_overflow/str_replace/file_get_contents_method.png

Ideally  I Am hoping for it to work as it would with the include method, but show up where the file_get_contents method puts it.

Comment: You're missing a quote after {PAGE_SIDEBAR}

Comment: Ah, typo as I typed it up separately for my post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to capture everything that the `include` spits out using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to be able to use it as a string:

```
ob_start();
include("template/sidebar.php");
$str_sidebar = ob_get_clean();
$body = str_replace("{PAGE_SIDEBAR}", $str_sidebar, $body);
echo $body;
```

If there are lots of placeholders that you want to replace, you might want to use a regular-expression based solution with a callback so that you don't have to repeat this code for each. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784039/50079) for a primer.

Comment: Good answer! include is a language construct and not a function.

Comment: Absolute winner, this is a perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to drop in and say that, three years later, this answer really helped me out.  Thanks!