# PHP - How remove blank line where placeholder used to be?

Tags: php, templates, placeholder

I came across this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784039/50079) while searching for a way to efficiently replace placeholders in a template file.

Everything seems to be working however, there are some values which are optional and the best I've been able to do is replace the placeholders with empty strings, which still leaves blank lines.

The current code I'm testing with is below:

**test.php:**

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('test.html');

$pattern = '/{{{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}}}/';

$text = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'produce_replacement', $text);
echo $text;

function produce_replacement($match) {
    $producerName = 'evaluate_'.strtolower($match[1]);
    return function_exists($producerName) ? $producerName() : null;
}

function evaluate_test1() {
        ob_start();
    include'test_include.php';
    $test4 = ob_get_clean();
    return $test4;
}

function evaluate_footer() {
    if (isset($blah)) {
        $val = 'some string';
    } else {
        $val = '';
    }   
    return $val;
}
?>
```

**test.html (template file):**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Test1: {{{test1}}}</p>
<p>Test2: {{{test2}}}</p>
<p>Test3: {{{test3}}}</p>
<p>Test4: {{{test4}}}</p>
{{{footer}}}
</body>
</html>
```

**test_include.php:**

```
<?php
$a = 'Hi, ';
$b = 'jeff!';
echo $a.$b;
?>
```

So `{{{footer}}}` will be replaced with `$val` which will be either *some string* or a blank line will remain. How can I get rid of that blank line?

Comment: That isn't really how template files are supposed to work. Consider that you actually have `{{{footer}}}\n` where the `\n` is part of your template file. Typically, you don't want your template engine to just discard characters in the template file (how could the engine know that the `\n` isn't intentional?) so it not removing the newline is expected and probably good behavior. Why not just move `{{{footer}}}` to the end of the previous line?

Comment: You should use a real template library, it will allow you to write conditional expressions.

Comment: @TheGentleman - Moving `{{{footer}}}`  to the end of the previous line will get rid of the blank line but if  `{{{footer}}}` is not empty, I guess I can do `$val = "\n".'<div>some string</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected. The newline character exists in your template file, you need to update it:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Test1: {{{test1}}}</p>
<p>Test2: {{{test2}}}</p>
<p>Test3: {{{test3}}}</p>
<p>Test4: {{{test4}}}</p>
{{{footer}}}</body>
</html>
```

However I don't see the problem with that whitespace, a browser would not render it anyway.